# Использование оперативной памяти

Tags: windows-10

После 7-8 часов использования компьютера используется почти вся оперативная память. В диспетчере задач отображается, что использую только 2гб. Такое происходит каждый день, после перезагрузки все нормально. Что это может быть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смотрите в «подробностях» кто ест память

Comment: Мало информации что бы сделать какие-либо выводы, надо процессы и службы смотреть.

Comment: Я могу как-то логи выгрузить? чтобы изображениями не кидать